# How does "first" property in ace:datatable work?

Tags: java, jsf, pagination, icefaces-3, ace-datatable

We're trying to put 3 tables in the same page with some kind of synchronized pagination. Because of the "paginator" property in ace:datatable is individual for each table, we're using some commandLinks to implement the functionality of moving forward and backward.

We've tried with de "page" property in the tables, linked all of them to a property in the backing-bean that is incremented or decremented with the commandLink's action method. But this "page" property only works when "paginator" property is set to true. And because we don't want to show paginator itself (with numbered pages, an buttons and everything else), we can't use this property.

We've tried too with the "first" property of the ace:datatable, and again binding this property to the backing-bean. But it doesn't do anything: when we change this property's value, the tables remain in the same position of the list that populates them.

We're populating the table with a personalized ArrayList (where  is a class that matches a table in the database). And only got the thing work when enabling paginator in the tables and used "page" property.

And we've used a Datamodel object too, but with no positive results.

So, what does "first" property of ace:datatable serving for? (Please, don't tell me the API definition of this property, I've read it many times ;) ). One colleague says that he made it work when he used an ice:datatable, instead of the ACE one.

Does anyone know a better solution to implement this scenario (3 datatables with the same pagination, so when yo click to "move forward", all of them move to the same position)?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I've received response through the IceSoft forum. nils.lundquist says:

> The cause of this issue appears to have been some legacy pagination code in the library that the ace:dataTable was forked from. It isn't recognizable as part of our features, so I've corrected the issue and, assuming testing goes well, the fix will appear in our coming release (beta also).
>
> Note that first still won't have an effect when component controlled pagination is enabled, and I've adjusted the TLD to reflect this. First will now actually work when pagination is disabled.

Referring to iceFaces 3.1.0 beta02, releasing this week.

If anyone knows a better way to solve this case (3 dataTables with pagination linked) any help will be apreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the upgrade to IceFaces 3.1.0